# How to read huge files with samll ram in golang?

Tags: go, readfile

I have such document and I want to read each files in loop which is 5GB of size, I tried some way such as (file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)) but it's loads the entire file into memory.I used this func for load files:

```
func visit(files *[]string) filepath.WalkFunc {
    return func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        *files = append(*files, path)
        return nil
    }
}
```

and for read files I used:

```
file, err := os.Open("file")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    buf := make([]byte,10*1024)
    for {
        n, err := file.Read(buf)
        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Print(buf[:n])
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
```

I want to parse data from buf

```
err = xml.Unmarshal(buf, &m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(m)
```

m is:

```
type M struct {
Mc []struct {
Id string `xml:"id"`
NeId string `xml:"neid"`}`xml:"mc"`
Mr struct {
Mh  []string `xml:"mh"`}`xml:"mr"`
}
```

and in func main:

```
func main() {
    var files []string
    root := "/folder/files"
    err := filepath.Walk(root, visit(&files))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
    for _, file := range files {
```

but it takes too long time to execute, what should I do to fast this process? 
I get an error XML syntax error on line 496: unexpected EOF.
concurrency may be useful in this case?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what you want to _do_ with the file.

Comment: Reading a big file can take a long time. What exactly are you expecting, and what are you getting? Have you tried larger buffers? Have you tried using `bufio`?

Comment: When dealing with large files you usually want to stream-process them - read some (relatively) small chunk, do whatever processing you need, then read the next chunk, so you only have one chunk in memory at any given time. But, as Flimzy said, it's impossible to be more specific without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: All the down voters haven't seen Python's generator feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some reproducible benchmark results:

SSD:

```
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
$ go build readfile.go && time ./readfile
/home/peter/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso is 2103607296 bytes
real    0m2.839s
user    0m0.283s
sys     0m1.064s
$
```

HDD:

```
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
$ go build readfile.go && time ./readfile
/home/peter/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso is 2103607296 bytes
real    0m14.194s
user    0m0.627s
sys     0m2.880s
$
```

HDD:

```
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
$ go build readfile.go && time ./readfile
/home/peter/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso is 2103607296 bytes
real    0m16.627s
user    0m0.431s
sys     0m1.608s
$
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func readFile(fName string) (int64, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(fName)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)

    nr := int64(0)
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 4*1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
        buf = buf[:n]
        if n == 0 {
            if err == nil {
                continue
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return nr, err
        }

        // Do something with buf
        nr += int64(len(buf))

        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return nr, err
        }
    }
    return nr, nil
}

func main() {
    fName := `/home/peter/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso`
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        fName = os.Args[1]
    }
    nr, err := readFile(fName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s is %d bytes\n", fName, nr)
}
```

---

What are your reproducible benchmark results?

Comment: What is the difference between the two HDDs, just two runs?